# Insert jquery variable into ajax destination url

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have retrieved records from a mysql database and displayed it in my page using a loop. In each record displayed on the page(I have 4), there is a button and a span element with classes "decrease" and "quantity" respectively among other things. When I click on the decrease button, it uses ajax to reduce the "quantity" on the database by 1 and then returns the new value which I would like to display in the "quantity" span element as a text. Now I have been able to get all this to work except in one area. After the new quantity is returned, it changes the "quantity" value of ALL records displayed instead of the one in the same container as the button that was clicked. Can anyone please show me where I went wrong in my coding.

Here's an excerpt of the code that displays the data:

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($run) >= 1){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $quantity = $row['quantity'];
                        $price = $row['price'];
                        $image = $row['image'];
                        $category = $row['category'];
                        $total = $price * $quantity;
                        echo "<div class=\"post-container\">\n";
                        echo "<div class=\"post-thumb\">\n";
                        echo "<img src='$image'>\n";
                        echo "</div>\n";
                        echo "<div class=\"post-title\">\n";
                        echo "<h4 style=\"font-weight:bold;\">\n";
                        echo "<a href=\"view.php?name=$name&category=$category\" class=\"links\" target=\"_blank\">$name</a>\n";
                        echo "<span id=\"deletion\">Delete</span>\n";
                        echo "</h4>\n";
                        echo "</div>\n";
                        echo "<div class=\"post-content\">\n";
                        echo "<ul style=\"list-style-type:none;\">\n";
                        echo "<li>Cost Per Item: <span id=\"cost\">$price</span>/=</li>\n";
                        echo "<li>\n";
                        echo "Quantity: \n";
                        echo "<button type=\"submit\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus decrease\" title=\"Decrease Quantity\"></button>\n";
                        echo "\n";
                        echo "<span id=\"cost\" class=\"quantity\">&nbsp$quantity&nbsp</span>\n";
                        echo "\n";
                        echo "<button type=\"submit\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus increase\" title=\"Increase Quantity\"></button>\n";
                        echo "</li>\n";
                        echo "<li>Total Cost: <span id=\"cost\">$total</span>/=</li>\n";
                        echo "</ul>\n";
                        echo "</div>\n";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
```

And here's an excerpt of the jquery:

```
$(".decrease").click(function(){
        var itemName = $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent("div.post-content").siblings("div.post-title").find("a").text();
        $.post(
            "decrease-cart.php?username=<?php echo $username?>",
            {name: itemName},
            function(result){
                $(this).siblings(".quantity").text(result);
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use $(this) inside a ajax callback

```
$.post(
    "decrease-cart.php?username=<?php echo $username?>",
    {name: itemName},
    function(result){
        $(this).siblings(".quantity").text(result);
    }
);
```

I don't thing you should use $(this) there directly

Do like this, store your selected node in a temporary variable

```
$(".decrease").click(function(){
    var __temp = $(this);
    var itemName = __temp.parent("li").parent("ul").parent("div.post-content").siblings("div.post-title").find("a").text();
    $.post(
        "decrease-cart.php?username=<?php echo $username?>",
        {name: itemName},
        function(result){
            __temp.siblings(".quantity").text(result);
        }
    );
});
```